# JavaScript React: Issues with passing prop from a function in a child component to a function in the parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

I'm dealing with a problem passing a prop to a parent component from it's child.

The idea of the code that I'm trying to make work is a set of buttons in a header component that when clicked, load new component pages for other parts of the website. I'm dealing with a couple of smaller bugs that I can fix at another time but the primary issue is when I try to pass the results of the function for handling the switch and the values showing as 'undefined' once they get to the App component. I doubt I'm explaining it well so allow me to show the code.

Parent Component (App)

```
import React from "react";
import Header from "./Components/Header/Header";
import Footer from "./Components/Footer/Footer";
import Pane from "./Components/Pane/Pane";
import MainPane from "./Components/Pane/MainPane";
import BookViewPane from "./Components/Pane/BookViewPane";
import AddBookPane from "./Components/Pane/AddBookPane";
import SignInPane from  "./Components/Pane/SignInPane";
import "./App.css";

const App = ()=>{

    function LoadPaneHandler(props){
        var NewPaneName=props.paneName;

        // const NewPaneName={
        //  name: props.paneName
        // };
        
        // const NewPaneName=String(props);

        console.log(NewPaneName);
        switch(NewPaneName){
            case 'MainPane':
                return <MainPane />
            case 'AddBookPane':
                return <AddBookPane />
            case 'BookViewPane':
                return <BookViewPane />
            case 'SignInPane':
                return <SignInPane />
            default:
                return <Pane />
        }
    }

    return(
        <React.Fragment>
            <Header switchPane={LoadPaneHandler} />
            <main>
                <LoadPaneHandler paneName="MainPane" />
            </main>
            <Footer />
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Child Component (Header)

```
import React from "react";
import "./Header.css";

const Header=(props)=>{
    var paneName="";

    const switchPaneHandler=event=>{
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log(paneName);
        props.switchPane(paneName);
    }

    return(
        <header id="header">
            <div id="header-title">
                <h1>Library</h1>
            </div>
            <div id="header-buttons">
                <button onClick={paneName="BookViewPane",switchPaneHandler}> View Books</button>
                <button onClick={paneName="AddBookPane",switchPaneHandler}> Add Books </button>
                <button onClick={paneName="SignInPane",switchPaneHandler}> Login</button>
            </div>
        </header>
    );
}

export default Header;
```

I've included the commented out code of other approaches I've used to get the data I need for the function to work properly so that you can have an Idea of what I've already tried.

The code works fine so long as I only pass values to the function from within the App component. Whenever I click on one of the buttons in the header though, it shows the ***'paneName'*** correctly in the ***'switchPaneHandler'*** function but then in ***'LoadPaneHandler'*** it prints as 'undefined'.

I'm still quite new to React so it's likely a very obvious mistake that I've made but any help is appreciated all the same. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the key issue here is probably caused by confusion about "What are props? What is state?" - very common when getting started with React.

If we look at the parent component first, you're passing `LoadPaneHandler` to your `Header` like it's a callback function. That's not how we do it in React. We need to supply a callback function that takes the name of the pane that we want the parent to show. Naming can *really help* too in order to make things clearer. Here's how I'd rewrite your parent:

```
const App = ()=>{
    const [currentPaneName, setCurrentPaneName] = React.useState("MainPane")
    
    function updateCurrentPane(newPaneName) {
      console.log(`Updating pane from ${currentPaneName} to ${newPaneName}`);
      setCurrentPaneName(newPaneName)
    }

    function LoadPaneHandler(){

        console.log(`Showing pane ${currentPaneName}`);
        switch(currentPaneName){
            case 'MainPane':
                return <MainPane />
            case 'AddBookPane':
                return <AddBookPane />
            case 'BookViewPane':
                return <BookViewPane />
            case 'SignInPane':
                return <SignInPane />
            default:
                return <Pane />
        }
    }

    return(
        <React.Fragment>
            <Header onNewPaneSelected={updateCurrentPane} />
            <main>
                <LoadPaneHandler />
            </main>
            <Footer />
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}
```

I've left a sprinkling of `console.log`s in there so you can get a feel for the timing of re-rendering and responding (*React*-ing) to change. If you're not familiar with `useState()`, this is the one React hook you absolutely *must* understand if you're going to build useful React applications - [here are the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html).

Now for the child. You've got a `paneName` variable but you don't need it. All you're really trying to do is set up the right argument when you call the callback:

```
const Header=(props)=>{

    const switchPaneHandler= (paneName) =>{
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log(paneName);
        props. onNewPaneSelected(paneName);
    }

    return(
        <header id="header">
            <div id="header-title">
                <h1>Library</h1>
            </div>
            <div id="header-buttons">
                <button onClick={() => switchPaneHandler("BookViewPane")}> View Books</button>
                <button onClick={() => switchPaneHandler("AddBookPane")}> Add Books </button>
                <button onClick={() => switchPaneHandler("SignInPane")}> Login</button>
            </div>
        </header>
    );
}
```

Note I changed the name of the callback function it's expecting to be given as a prop - `switchPane` was a bit misleading - it's not *this* component's job to switch panes, it just needs to be able to tell *someone* that the user wants to switch. This also makes it easier to make changes in the future, for example if you have other things that are interested in which pane the user wants to see.

Comment: This solved my problem completely! I gave state a passing glance back when this issue first came up but I clearly misread something (or just not enough) because it didn't seem like this was actually a state related issue at the time. Clearly it was and I'm going to be spending a lot more time studying it now. Thank you so much!

Comment: I do have one other question. How is the function 'LoadPaneHandler' in the parent component being called when I click a button? Obviously, it's called during the initial render but there's call for it to run during in 'updateCurrentPane' function nor anywhere else so I'm not exactly sure how the DOM is actually being updated. Is this one of the effects of State/Hooks where it automatically re renders the page?

Comment: Yep - you got it. That's one of the magic powers of the `useState()` hook - the "setter" that you get when you dereference the returned array (which I called `setCurrentPaneName`) will automatically cause everything from "here down" (i.e. your whole `App`) to re-render if it gets called with a different value to what it's already got.

Comment: That's actually really cool! Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your child component (Header) like this.

```js
import React from "react";
import "./Header.css";
const Header = (props) => {

    const switchPaneHandler = paneName => {
        console.log(paneName);
        props.switchPane(paneName);
    }

    return(
        <header id="header">
            <div id="header-title">
                <h1>Library</h1>
            </div>
            <div id="header-buttons">
                <button onClick={()=> switchPaneHandler('BookViewPane')}> View Books</button>
                <button onClick={() => switchPaneHandler("AddBookPane")}> Add Books </button>
                <button onClick={() => switchPaneHandler("SignInPane")}> Login</button>
            </div>
        </header>
    );
}
```

Comment: I did this and it did help to consistently pass the correct name for the new pane (which was one of the minor bugs I mentioned earlier) but sadly it didn't solve the larger problem. I did solve the issue with the help of another user though. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In header component your passing the paneName directly, but in parent component you are trying to get as javascript object (props.paneName), that is why you are getting error.

```
const switchPaneHandler=event=>{
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(paneName);
    props.switchPane(paneName);
}
```

so try to access directly,

```
function LoadPaneHandler(paneName){
    var NewPaneName = paneName;

    console.log(NewPaneName);
    switch(NewPaneName){
        case 'MainPane':
            return <MainPane />
        case 'AddBookPane':
            return <AddBookPane />
        case 'BookViewPane':
            return <BookViewPane />
        case 'SignInPane':
            return <SignInPane />
        default:
            return <Pane />
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you know how to prevent the creation of a JS object like this in React? I'm still not sure how that object was being created in the first place since it seems like I was only passing a single string variable to the function. I'm not sure how that would create an object unless react was doing something on its end.